# Good explanation/documentation on ftrace

Tags: linux, kernel, ftrace

I just read that the 2.6.27 kernel has a new module called ftrace which sounds a lot like suns dtrace utility. I'm having some trouble googling for documentation, I was wondering if anyone else had something. Is this something that is going to be implemented on the full programming stack like dtrace and we'll get a nice little scripting language for tracing in linux?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't have an explanation, but the [documentation is here](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.27/Documentation/ftrace.txt).